# Laravel 10 Try Catch no funciona?

Tags: laravel, excepciones

Estoy armando un mnodulo de contacto quiero validar un formulario

```
<?php

namespace Modules\ContactUs\App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use Modules\ContactUs\App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

use Modules\ContactUs\App\Models\Contact;

use Exception;

class ContactUsController extends Controller
{
    public array $data = [];

/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        try {

            $this->data = $request->validated();
            Contact::create($this->data);
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Formulario de contacto enviado con éxito']);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Hubo un problema al procesar la solicitud'], 500);
        }
    }
```

necesito que al enviar a este endpoint un dato en este caso nombre email y mensaje:

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'message' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
```

al enviar por ejemplo pepito email@gmail.com este mensaje.... se envia perfectamente y se guarda en la base de datos y devuelve el json de que todo esta correcto...

pero cuando envio pepito emailgmail.com y este mensaje... me muestra el index en el postman... necesito que no se guarde en la base de datos y me devuelva un json con el error recibido...

Comment: Prueba depurar el código para ver que está validando el request antes de llegar a insertar en la base de datos

Comment: En postman agrega la cabecera Accept: aplication/json pera que latavel sepa que debe devolver un json en vez de html

Comment: Si no se cumple alguna regla del formRequest (en tu caso `ContactFormRequest`), es el mismo formRequest el que devuelve el "error". Es decir, si una regla no se cumple no se ejecuta ninguna parte del método "store" de tu controlador, por eso no se llega a ver tu mensaje. Acá podés ver como customizar la [respuesta](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages).